# (Attribute Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array')

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm getting `Attribute Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array'` when I run my code.

I'm using python 3.6.5 and tensorflow 2.0.0

I imported numpy,utils ,vis but I still getting the same error

How can I resolve this issue?

```
import numpy as np
import os
# import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import urllib

from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

**here's the visualization part of my code**

```
# Visualization of the results of a detection.

vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image_np,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=4
)

cv2.imshow('Frame' ,cv2.resize(image_np ,(1280 ,960)))
if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
    break
```

What should I do?

Comment: What's `visualization_utils` or `vis_utils`? According to your error, Python is saying that it's a function and functions don't have attributes that can be accessed by `.` operator.

Comment: I am just starting with TensorFlow and came across the TensorFlow Object Detection and I'm following https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/camera.html

Comment: Since you've already imported `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` directly here in the line `from utils.visualization_utils import visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`, try `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(...)` instead of `vis_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(...)`.

Comment: I got this error instead 'NameError: name 'visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array' is not defined
'

Comment: But it is clearly defined in your import statements. Are you sure `from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from utils.visualization_utils import visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` is working correctly without any error?

Comment: the only error I'm getting `'function' object has no attribute`  but I removed that line anyway as it's unused line but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the python path before you run the program, you need to run the below line from the research folder -

---

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

---

Check the link for more information - 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#add-libraries-to-pythonpath